# What is the PowerShell alternative for !$ which refers to the last argument from previous command in tcsh?

Tags: powershell

From my linux days I remember that `!$` was a really useful shortcut to get the last argument from the previous command on the tcsh command prompt.

Does PowerShell has anything like this?

(it must be short, not anything like `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Last(((Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine -split ' '))`)

Comment: Why not create a function that returns `[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Last(((Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine -split ' '))`?

Comment: I could. But I am interested to know if the shell itself has a built-in shortcut, like tcsh does. But you can arrange your comment as an answer. It is a viable option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `$$` automatic variable. There is also `$^` that means "first token in last line received by the session."

I recommend reading the `about_Automatic_Variables` help topic for more information.